# Convert a react JavaScript website into APK for remote testing?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, apk

I am developing a web app in react. It is a sort of a game/world style thing that I wanted to put on my phone that I can just pass to people to try out on my phone.
I was wondering if there's a way to package the assets so it appears like any other app on my phone which I can just press and it functions same as npm start.
I'm very new to web development and not from this field.
Thanks a bunch.

I tried googling but the answers aren't clear so hoping to get a more detailed response here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like a PWA (Progressive Web App). In short, it is a web application that you can install on any mobile device that supports a browser. All you need to do is host your application and meet the conditions for installing your app, e.g. icon, manifest, performance, etc. You have probably ever encountered a situation where when you visited a website, the web browser asked if you wanted to install this application on your device - this is PWA. Any web application can be transformed into a PWA. This application can work completely without an Internet connection. It will appear on your device as an icon, exactly as you want. You can find a little more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps

If you need more help, ask.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

When you open a **React** app in Chrome on your Android device, click on the three dots to the right of the address bar. This will show a menu with the option `Install App` which will then install the app directly on your device. This only seems to appear for React apps, as the menu option isn't there for other web pages.

Once installed, you can then drag this 'installed app' anywhere on your device's home screen, and run it with one click.

When you open the app, there will be no address bar, or Chrome buttons, so you get a full screen experience, as if it were a genuine Android app.

I've tried this on both a Pixel 6 and Samsung Galaxy Tab, and it works very well.

[image]